# Cannot vertically center multiple divs within a div, and vertically center their elements within them

Tags: html, css, divider

I'm quite new to HTML/CSS and trying to understand a lot of the concepts involved. I'm trying to vertically center 2 divs within a larger div, and also center the elements within those divs.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="MainDiv">

      <div id="SubDiv">
        <form method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="example1" class="Text">
            <input type="text" name="example2" class="Text">
            <input type="submit" value="Go"> <br>
        </form> <br/>
      </div>

      <div id="SubDiv">
          <input type="button" value="Button 1"/>
          <input type="button" value="Button 2"/>
      </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#MainDiv 
{
    width: 60%;
    height: 30%;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    border:  1px solid black;
}

#SubDiv
{
    width: 90%;
    height: 45;
    margin: auto;
    border:  1px solid black;

}

.Text
{
    width: 40%;
}
```

[You can see the result here: the main div completely centered, but I'm unable to control the vertical centering of anything else.](http://liveweave.com/x6ulkn)

Naturally, I've done a lot of searching trying to fix this, but any fixes seem to either do nothing or mess things up even more. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen this site: http://howtocenterincss.com It's a great for centering in CSS

Comment: you forget to add the `position` property for other elements and also these properties `top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;` and atribute `id` should be unique, but you apply it to more than one element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to consider flexbox for this, which has vertical centering built in

Great intro to flexbox here:
http://flexboxin5.com/

Answer (score 0):

Vertically centered is a bit hard compared to horizontally centered.

To do that, I have set a container on your Subdivs elements and set an id `SubDivContainer`. Then set style for that container making it vertically centered.

```
#SubDivContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
}
```

**Putting together:**

```css
#MainDiv 
{
  width: 60%;
  height: 120px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  border:  1px solid black;
}

#SubDivContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
}

#SubDiv
{
  width: 90%;
  height: 45;
  margin: auto;
  border:  1px solid black;
  
}

.Text
{
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="MainDiv">
          <div id="SubDivContainer">
            <div id="SubDiv">
              <form method="POST">
                  <input type="text" name="example1" class="Text">
                  <input type="text" name="example2" class="Text">
                  <input type="submit" value="Go"> <br>
              </form> <br/>
            </div>

            <div id="SubDiv">
                <input type="button" value="Button 1"/>
                <input type="button" value="Button 2"/>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one  way of doing it.
I've wraped 2 inner divs in 1 div container and center it.
All elements inside inner divs are aligne with line height property set to height of div and I remove BR elements.

```css
body, html{height: 100%}
.mainDiv 
{
    width: 60%;
    height: 30%;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    border:  1px solid black;
}
.mainDiv>div{
    height: 90px;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.mainDiv>div>div{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    border:  1px solid black;
 line-height: 45px;
}

.mainDiv input[type=text]{
    width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="MainDiv" class="mainDiv">
      <div>
        <div>
          <form method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="example1">
            <input type="text" name="example2">
            <input type="submit" value="Go">
          </form>
        </div>

        <div>
          <input type="button" value="Button 1"/>
          <input type="button" value="Button 2"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```